# How to make a dataframe globally accessible from within a function without assigning it to a variable (in psychopy)?

Tags: python-3.x, psychopy

I have a function that executes several commands and creates a dataframe at the end:

```html
def Pos_Presentation():
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Date', 'Time', 'Session','Condition','Stimulus','Response_Type','Reaction_Time'])
    return df
```

I want for the dataframe (df) to be created and accessible outside of the function. But when I try:

```html
Pos_Presentation()
df
```

I get an error:

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-00cf07b74dcd> in <module>
----> 1 df

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

I tried:

```html
def Pos_Presentation():
        global df
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Date', 'Time', 'Session','Condition','Stimulus','Response_Type','Reaction_Time'])
        return df

Pos_Presentation()
df
```

In Jupyter_Notebook, this works. But in Psychopy, which is where I need to run it, it gives me an error:

```html
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

I cannot assign this function to a variable (like, var = Pos_Presentation()), because it does a bunch of other stuff other than generating the dataframe.

Comment: You can, and should, assign the return value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to assign the output of PosPresentation() to df, like this:

```
def Pos_Presentation():
    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Date', 'Time', 'Session','Condition','Stimulus','Response_Type','Reaction_Time'])
    return df

df = Pos_Presentation()
```

Also, I don't think you need "global df" in your function definition and it'll probably be easier to keep track of your dataframes if you give them different names (e.g., call the one in the function "df" but the one outside the function "Pos_df" or something).